# Filtering items in a column in Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, filter

I have an Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel in which I defined several columns.

Per each of the columns, I would like to allow the user to select a subset of items and then present only the rows that contain the selected values.

I thought of something similar to Excel's filter option.

I could not find a method that suits my needs in the Ext 3.3.1 API documentation but I am very new to this so it is quite possible I missed it...

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your grid panel will be getting data from some kind of data.store http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-cfg-store. And there is a way to apply filters according to your rules. See the method description on Sencha documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter